# How to share single SqlLite database between Unity and native android?

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, unityscript

How do I share a single SqlLite database between Unity and native android?

For unity, I suppose .db file has to be in 'StreamingAssets' folder. So considering this, is it possible to access shared database?

I can think of a way of hosting a service which can handle the query and communicate with database.
How about creating a plugin in native android, and use in unity to communicate shared database? is it possible?

I am looking for a way to further explore and implement it. What will be a best way to accomplish this problem?

Solution has to be offline.

Comment: Does Unity support the [shared user ID](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid)?

Comment: does it? @CL. I am not sure

Comment: If you use custom data reader/adapter style methodology then you can specify where to house the database file manually. Can you at least show how you're reading the file? In situations like this, I'd opt for a web api to interface with the database from multiple sources, but appreciate that this isn't always possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about two separate apps that need to use the same database. Let's break the problem down.

When it comes to using a database on either platform, your solution starts with having access to the location of the file. Once you've got access to the location of the file, then it's just a matter of accessing that database as if there was no second app.

If you put the database into some location that is accessible by any app then by definition it will be accessible by both of your apps. Anywhere like Envrionment.getExternalStorageDirectory() will work for this purpose.

However, if you want it to be *only* accessed by your two apps, then you're talking a different ball game which touches on data security. You've got two main options:

- Put the database in a location that is only accessible by your two apps
- Encrypt the database so that only your two apps can do anything with it

The first option involves looking into two apps sharing an *internal* storage directory. This will involve something like the lines of getting the two apps to share a user id like what [CL was mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344465/how-to-share-single-sqllite-database-between-unity-and-native-android/42346408#comment71840640_42344465).

The second option involves putting the database in an external storage directory and then looking into how to encrypt a database with some sort of key and then using that key in your two apps to open the database.

An important thing to note is that even if you were to go for the first option, if someone has a rooted phone they can still access the internal storage so you wouldn't have dealt with the security issue but that might be out of scope.

Hope this helps.